# Shell Case Without Accumulate Options

Tags: shell

I want that the option -h can just be used alone without accumulate with any other options for example (-h -l). How can I do it?

```
case $1 in
-h)help;;
-f)aa;;
esac

case $2 in
-l)bb;;
esac

case $3 in
-p)cc;;
esac
```

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work with what you have above?

Comment: -h -l -p can be used, but i just want that can be used only -h without -l or -p (calls the function help an stop without call bb and cc).

Comment: Why don't you just exit in the `help` section?

Answer (score 1):

Example code

```
  #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                           

    while getopts "ha" opt; do
      case $opt in
        a)
          echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
          ;;
        h)
          echo "-h was triggered!" >&2
          ;;
      esac
    done
```

Test case

```
 ./example.bash -a -h
-a was triggered!
-h was triggered!
```